# Should spring-data-jdbc EntityRowMapper be allowed to skip properties not in source map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jdbc

We are considering introducing Spring Data JDBC into our existing project, to minimize boilerplate code - but we ran into a snag: 
we have bean-classes that capture all the columns in a table, but we use queries that do not retrieve all the columns since some of the values happen not to be needed in a certain context. Spring Data JDBC's default `EntityRowMapper` throws an exception when the source map is missing a property that is present in the bean.

Would it be reasonable to expect that this default `EntityRowMapper` ought to be able to ignore those properties? (indicate it is ok to skip them when creating the result object or have an annotation that allows the programmer to specify a default value to use when it is missing from the source map)

Comment: This might be better suited for an issue on the issue tracker.

Comment: @JensSchauder I thought about that - but I was hoping to poll SO wisdom, first, before putting together a more complete/formal ticket ...

Answer (score 0):

Is it reasonable to expect something like that? Sure, why not.

The reason why it currently isn't this way is two-fold:

1. If it would be the default behavior it would be easy to select a column with a wrong name and end up with a `null` value in the entity, without noticing that something went bad.
2. I consider it bad style. If you just want some of the columns/attributes use a return type that has exactly those columns/attributes

Comment: As to (1), I could see something like `@Column("COL_NAME", optionalOnRead=true)` so that one would have to ask for it explicitly.  As for (2) - I think you may be right, though I would worry about a proliferation of slightly different classes, when multiple queries need just slightly different subsets of the data from the source table.